# Degree of an holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

We have $f(z)=\frac {z^{3}}{1-z^{2}} $
I have found that $0$ is a zero of order $3$, $-1$ and $+1$ simple poles and order $-1$, and $\infty$ isn't a ramification point,
but I have no clue how to show that the degree of f is $3$, does someone have an idea?
thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of the degree?

Comment: Where did you find such a bizarre definition? What, if any, textbooks on complex analysis are you reading?

Comment: can you give the exact definition?

Comment: The usual definition is the number of points in the preimage of a regular (noncritical) value.

Comment: so here in this case how can we explain it

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following result.

**Lemma.** Let $g$ and $h$ be two coprime univariate complex polynomials. Assume that $g$ is nonconstant. Then the degree $d$ of the rational mapping $f=\frac{g}{h}\colon \mathbb{C}_\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is given by $d=\operatorname{max}\{\operatorname{deg}(g),\operatorname{deg}(h)\}$.

For a proof see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607557/degree-of-an-holomorphic-map-and-ramification-points/4630343#4630343).

Applying this lemma to your example, we immediately see that your mapping has degree $3$.